# Why do people redact MAC addresses?

Tags: privacy, mac-address, confidentiality, sensitive-data-exposure

What are the security implications of sharing a MAC address online? How important is it really, to redact this information; and why?

I see it a lot, and I'm in the habit of doing it myself.

**1. Censored images**
Redacted and obscured images, PDFs, diagrams, blurred & pixelated screenshots & photographs.

**2. Obfuscated plaintext**
I've obfuscated individual characters with arbitrary symbols, like `#`, `*`, `•`, `★`, `?`, `x`, `-`, `_`, `.`, etc.

**3. Masked plaintext**
I've masked them with functional, yet obvious substitutes, like `FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF` & `A1:B2:C3:D4:E5:F6`. And some not so obvious, randomly generated, hex-encoded, colon delimited, binary octets.

Comment: Please focus on your question. Your question is contained in the first two sentences, the rest are mostly irrelevant information.

Comment: The script is nice and handy, but it isn't needed for the question. So I took the liberty of removing it. If you need the code, it is still available in the edit history.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich The question's in the title, mate. The body's entirely non-essential. It's all relevant though.